# java chat (serversocket/socket)

Tags: java

I need to build an application Server module - a console application for communication clients on principle chat,the client module - a GUI application chat, which must be connected to the server.
The problem is i need set limits on the number of connected users limits i get from configuration file whitch is read when the server starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put condition in your while loop?

```
try {

        int numOfConnectionLimit = 10; // or read number of connection from that config file

        ServerSocket listenerServ = new ServerSocket(servPort);
        System.out.println("Waiting...." + servPort + " "
                + "" + listenerServ.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        while (connectArray.size() < numOfConnectionLimit) {

            sock = listenerServ.accept();
            connectArray.add(sock);
            System.out.println("Client connected from: " + sock.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
            addUserName(sock);

            SocketChatServerReturn chat = new SocketChatServerReturn(sock);
            Thread X = new Thread(chat);
            X.start();

        }
    } catch (Exception exSock) {
        System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + exSock);
        exSock.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that while (++i <= numOfConnectionLimit) ?

Comment: Yes, but I editted my answer, it is now based on number of items in your `connectArray`. You can still use the variable to count number of connections.

Comment: your answer is exactly what i need, but what if i need to send msg for Client at LogInForm to show him at JoptionPane "server is busy"

Comment: I will use the `Multicasting` technique. The client will connect first to multicast server and that client will send msg to the server if there's a connection slot then, the server will response to client that there's a slot and can now connect to `ServerSocket`. If not, then server will reply to client that "Server is busy"

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/multicasting_in_java.shtml or you can **Google java multicasting tutorial**

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of successful accepts and don't accept any more if you hit your limit.

Comment: Also do take care to decrease the count by 1 if user logs out